# designing table when page is loaded

Tags: javascript, php

**xxx.js**

```
tableCreationForQuoteItem();

function tableCreationForQuoteItem()
{
    var html_str='';
    html_str += '<table>';
    html_str += '<tr>';
    html_str += '<th>Item</th><th>Description</th><th>Unit Cost</th><th>Tax Rate</th><th>Unit Of Measurement</th>';
    html_str += '</tr>';
    html_str += '<tr>';
    html_str += '<td>'+$('#Quote_quoteitem_name')   +'</td>';
    html_str += '<td>'+$('#Quote_description')      +'</td>';
    html_str += '<td>'+$('#Quote_unitcost')         +'</td>';
    html_str += '<td>'+$('#Quote_taxrate_value')    +'</td>';
    html_str += '<td>'+$('#Quote_uom_value')        +'</td>';
    html_str += '</tr>';
    html_str += '</table>';
    alert(html_str);
}
```

**I am getting the alert. But I want to place this table in certain field like Quote_item. How this can be done? Someone help please.**

Comment: 'Quote_item' is the id of field or what ?

Comment: yes id of the another text field.

Comment: Looks like jQuery, so why would you do it this way, and what exactly do you expect when concantenating a string and a jQuery object. Also, you never append the table anywhere ?

Comment: I think this plugin will helpful for you - http://datatables.net/

Comment: U should use jquery too. The function you made should be excecuted when your document is ready. So in jquery this is `$(document).ready(function tableCreationForQuoteItem(){` Then, when you write your table to the content of your division you should search the tag by his ID and change the innerHTML of this tag. Like this `document.getElementById("Quote_item").innerHTML = html_str;` [For a demo, check this](http://jsfiddle.net/Callie_/pHz8u/1/)

Comment: getting [object Object]. what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery -

```
$('#Quote_item').html(html_str);
```

and using javascript -

```
document.getElementById("Quote_item").innerHTML = html_str;
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably want something more like this

```
function tableCreationForQuoteItem() {
    var table = $('<table />'),
        tr1   = $('<tr />'),
        tr2   = $('<tr />'),
        th1   = $('<th />', {text : 'Item'}),
        th2   = $('<th />', {text : 'Description'}),
        th3   = $('<th />', {text : 'Unit Cost'}),
        th4   = $('<th />', {text : 'Tax Rate'}),
        th5   = $('<th />', {text : 'Unit Of Measurement'}),
        td1   = $('<td />', {text : $('#Quote_quoteitem_name').text()}),
        td2   = $('<td />', {text : $('#Quote_description').text()}),
        td3   = $('<td />', {text : $('#Quote_unitcost').text()}),
        td4   = $('<td />', {text : $('#Quote_taxrate_value').text()}),
        td5   = $('<td />', {text : $('#Quote_uom_value').text()});


    table.append(
        tr1.append(
            th1, th2, th3, th4, th5 
        ),
        tr2.append(
            td1, td2, td3, td4, td5 
        )
    );

    $('element').append(table);
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/DFWc4/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really get the question and since I don't have the required reputation to comment, I will give you the answer based on my predictions;

If you want the provided table to appear inside the HTML body ( for example  ) then simply replace alert box with

`document.getElementbyID("quote_item").innerHTML = html_str;`

If you want the entire HTML to appear in the ,

create a pre tag inside a  tag inside the

`

pre id="quote_item"

/pre`

and replace the alert box in your javascript with;
`document.getElementbyID("quote_item").innerHTML = html_str;`

P.S: enclose pre inside < >, stackoverflow's overriding it into an HTML content, not sure how the quotes here work as I'm still new :S